# what is the purpose of the returnURL that some developers pass to Actions methods?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

i have seem some developers when they develop `Login()`, `logout()` actions put two parameters to the methods, first one is the `login model` and second a `string returnURL`. But i can login and logout a user without having the second paramter (`returnURL`) because i just need remove the authentication cookie and call `redirectToAction("action", "controller")` will return to the view i want after logout or login

So why some developers pass `returnURL` as the second parameter? any special reason associated with it? When i use `returnURL` as a parameter with another method `getCustomers(int id, string returnURL)` is there a meaning in it?

Comment: Let's take an example, You are on a add Employee page and your session expires. now, after login you want to load user on the same page which is `add Employee`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`redirectToAction("action", "controller")` works fine if your redirect is to a constant place.  But that's not necessarily the case.  When logging in, often you have captured a user's attempt to go to some restricted URL.  Then you want to forward them to their original destination - wherever that may be - after the login is successful.  In other cases, there may be multiple navigation paths that take a user to a screen, and you want a "Return" or "Cancel" button to take them back to where they were - wherever that may be.